# Systems of equations algebraically using the quadratic formula

Tags: quadratics

$$y=-x^2+2x+9$$
$$y=-5x^2+10x+12$$
Round answer to two decimal places.

So far I made both equations equal the other which lead to $-4x^2+8x+12$, took $4$ out, $4 (-x^2+2x+3)$. Then that bracketed terms were put into the quadratic formula to equal $(-1 \pm \sqrt{2})/(-1)$

That answer doesn't seem right, but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Quadratic formula :

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Out of interest, what do you think the quadratic formula is? Because $b^2-4ac=4-4*(-1)*3=16$, so not sure where you got $\sqrt 2$ from

Comment: I edited your answer, hopefully, I didn't make any errors.  I did put parentheses that were missing around the numerator in the quadratic formula - was this what you were missing?

Comment: You said that the equations lead to $-4x^2+8x+12$, but this is only an expression, not an equation.  Perhaps you meant $-4x^2+8x+12=0$?  I know that this doesn't look like much, but it makes a big difference.

Comment: @Michael Burr Yes, that's what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: I got $(-2 \pm \sqrt{7})/(-2)$ as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$y=-x^2+2x+9$$ and $$y=-5x^2+10x+12$$ eliminating $y$ we have
$$-5x^2+10x+12=-x^2+2x+9$$
and from here we get a quadratic equation
$$0=4x^2-8x-3$$
using the quadratic fomula we obtain:
$$x_1=\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{2}$$
or
$$x_2=\frac{2-\sqrt{7}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! how would I round these answers to two decimal places? Would it be -0.32 and 2.32?And I got -2 in my answer, how did you get positive 2?

Comment: what you have :  $(-2 \pm \sqrt{7})/(-2)$ is very essentially the same exact thing as $(2 \pm \sqrt{7})/2$.  Just cancel the negative on the top and bottom, or if you like, multiply the numerator and the denominator by $-1$.  I suspect that the quadratic you used was the exact same as the one in this answer multiplied by $-1$.    Also, yes if they say round to two decimal places your answers meet those requirements.